# I could use some assistance getting CSS subclass (?) to work

Tags: css, css-selectors

Could I get a little help with this CSS? In my stylesheet I have my anchor colors defined:

```
a:link {}
a:visited {}
a:hover {}
```

Later on in the stylesheet, I have some anchors that are within a span defined as:

```
span.logout {}
span.logout a:link, a:visited {}
span.logout a:hover {}
```

The only thing is, my anchor colors in the logout span are overriding my primary anchor colors. I am confused as to why this is happening. I thought only the anchors within the "logout" span would be affected by this CSS.

Anyway, if anybody could help out with this, I would appreciate it. Also, am I using the term CSS "subclass" correctly?

Thanks for taking the time to read, and have a great day. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `a:visited` selector is standing on its own, without being qualified by the `span.logout` selector, because the comma separates it. In other words, it's the same as if you had two rules like this, with the same set of declarations:

```
span.logout a:link {}
a:visited {}
```

This has the effect of overriding your previous `a:visited` rule even for visited links within `span.logout`.

You need to repeat the `span.logout` selector after the comma for it to take effect only within such `span` elements:

```
span.logout a:link, span.logout a:visited {}
```

CSS does not have a notion of "subclasses" in that all classes are treated the same, but your use here seems fine. I suppose the term "subclass" would have a clearer definition in something like [OOCSS](http://oocss.org), though, which is but a CSS coding technique.

I would call your selector a [contextual selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS1/#contextual-selectors), in that you're applying styles only to visited links in the *context* of `span.logout` elements (technically, the space separating `span.logout` and `a:visited` is called a [descendant combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#descendant-combinators)).

Comment: I'll be darned. I was under the impression that I could combine the anchors under the span, I thought it was "shorthand". Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change:

```
span.logout a:link, a:visited {}
```

to:

```
span.logout a:link, span.logout a:visited {}
```

the comma is separating the selectors, so all `a:visited` links are targeted with the second set of styles